# jQuery object index ignores jQuery.filter()

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, indexing

The method chain:

```
$("someSelector").filter("someMoreSpecificSelector").index()
```

should return the index of the element in the jQuery filtered array.

It actually **returns the same** as:

```
$("someSelector").index()
```

even though the jQuery array changed greatly when the filtering happened.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Doc said :

> ## index()
>
> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

http://api.jquery.com/index/

So it mean your code is currently checking its position among it children. So if you code look like that :

```
<div>
    <p>
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <p id='yay'>
    </p>
</div>
```

Those 2 snippet will return the same thing :

```
$('div p').index(); //0
$('div p').filter('#yay').index(); //0
```

`.index()` accept argument. When passing a DOM object, you will have the current position of the object inside the jQuery object

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

So you can use that :

```
var $collection = $("someSelector");
$collection.index($collection.filter('someMoreSpecificSelector'))
```